# c# Dependency injection error - Hopefully a fairly simply issue for those that understand

Tags: c#, webapi

I have extracted what I hope I the relevant sections of code

```
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IServerInfoRepository, ServerInfoRepository>();
```

```
    public class ServerInfoRepository : IServerInfoRepository
    {

      private readonly ServerContext _context;
    
            
      public ServerInfoRepository(ServerContext servers)
        {
            _context = servers  ??throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(servers));
            }
```

```
     public IAsyncEnumerable<Server> Servers { get; set; } = AsyncEnumerable.Empty<Server>();
    
            public ServerContext()
            {
            }
```

For which I get the error

```
System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: ServerInfoAPI.Interfaces.IServerInfoRepository Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: ServerInfoAPI.Repositories.ServerInfoRepository': Unable to resolve service for type 'ServerInfoAPI.Context.ServerContext' while attempting to activate 'ServerInfoAPI.Repositories.ServerInfoRepository'.)
  Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateServiceProvider(Object containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\gbalaam\source\repos\ServerInfoAPI\ServerInfoAPI\Program.cs:line 38

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: ServerInfoAPI.Interfaces.IServerInfoRepository Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: ServerInfoAPI.Repositories.ServerInfoRepository': Unable to resolve service for type 'ServerInfoAPI.Context.ServerContext' while attempting to activate 'ServerInfoAPI.Repositories.ServerInfoRepository'.

Inner Exception 2:
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'ServerInfoAPI.Context.ServerContext' while attempting to activate 'ServerInfoAPI.Repositories.ServerInfoRepository'.
```

Unfortunately I am not truly understanding the error.  I have commented out the ServerContext Code and that then compiles, so that suggest ServerContext is the issue, but that looks extremely harmless.

Is anyone able to explain to me what is going on, and how to tweak the code such that it works.

The expectation is that serverContext will contain a list of server objects loaded from config.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You have a type that is trying to inject `ServerInfoAPI.Context.ServerContext`, but you haven't set that type up when setting up your DI.

Comment: `Unable to resolve service for type 'ServerInfoAPI.Context.ServerContext'` is the main point of the error.  You need to tell DI what to inject for this object.

Comment: add scoped ServerContext class to the ServiceCollection as ServerInfoRepository and do not forget to pass connectionString.

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ServerContext>();
```

and all started to work

Comment: you must use Scoped DI Lifetime same as repository object, to prevent getting concurrency exception and also for the asynchron calls.